# How to create route to access denied page in Angular

Tags: angular

How is the path to page access denied in Angular?
I'm creating an "Access Denied" page for when the user without access tries to do something they can't.
Does anyone have any ideia on what I put there in the path of the Angular route?
Or do I need to do more than that?
Ah, the user system is that of the keycloak

I tried this:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {


    constructor(
        @Inject('InformacaoSistema') private sistema: BehaviorSubject<InformacaoSistema>,
        protected authTokenService: AuthTokenService,
        protected redirectService: RedirectService,
        protected router: Router) {
    }

    isAccessAllowed(): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            if (this.authTokenService.isExpired()) {
                this.authTokenService.getTokenNaSessionStorage();
            } else {
                return this.redirectService.returnLoginUrl();
            }
            const usuario: Usuario = this.authTokenService.setarUsuarioDaLocalStorage();
            this.configInformacoesSistema(usuario);
            resolve(true);
        });
    }

    configInformacoesSistema(usuario: Usuario) {
        if (usuario) {
            const informacoes = {
                nome: usuario.nome,
                nomeExibido: usuario.nomeExibido,
                matricula: usuario.matricula,
                cnpjs: usuario.cnpjs,
                sistema: 'CLASSIND',
                sistemaDescricao: 'Sistema de Classificação Indicativa',
                versaoBackend: '1.0.0',
                versaoFrontend: '1.0.0',
            } as any;
            this.sistema.next(informacoes);
        }
    }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean
        | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return this.isAccessAllowed();
    }

    canActivateChild(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean
        | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return this.isAccessAllowed();
    }


}
```

And:

```
{
    path: '',
    component:PaginaAcessoNegadoComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

Comment: if access is denied then you can redirect to path `access-denied` already defined in app-routing file, and to check for access is denied or not is inside auth guard.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I do this in the files? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

in the class that implements canActivateChild

```
canActivateChild(

        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,

        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {

        if (this.checkPermissao(route.data.permissao) && state.url) {

            return true;

        } else {

            this.router.navigate(['acesso-restrito']);

            return false;

        }

    }
```

in rounting.module.ts

```
{ path: ‘acesso-restrito’,

    component: PaginaAcessoNegadoComponent,

    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]
},
```